# jQuery datatables add class to tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery and datatables.  I want to add a class to the TR element of a particular row.  I know how to find the row. The `console.dir(row);` shows the `row` object and that starts with a `tr` element.  I can't get the jQuery selector to do anything though.  What am I missing?

```
table = $('#resultTable').DataTable({
    aaSorting: [],
    ajax: {...},
    columnDefs: [...],
    createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
        //
        // if the second column cell is blank apply special formatting
        //
        if (data[1] == "") {
            console.dir(row);
            $('tr', row).addClass('label-warning');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't you just do `$(row).addClass('label-warning');`?

Comment: Why aren't you doing `$(row).addClass(...)`? If `row` is a `tr` itself, `$('tr', row)` (or `$(row).find('tr')`) will only find nested `tr`s.

Comment: heh, I *thought* I tried `$(row).addClass("label-warning");` without success... now it works. :-}

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`$('tr', row)` is looking for a tr element in the context of row, meaning it will search for a tr element **inside** the `row` provided as context parameter.

According to [API](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow), this should work

```
$(row).addClass("label-warning");
```

Comment: Thanks, as above I *thought* I had done this but I must have been making some other error.  Thanks

Answer (score 39):

You would just have to use the **createdRow**

```
$('#data-table').DataTable( {
    createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
        // Set the data-status attribute, and add a class
        $( row ).find('td:eq(0)')
            .attr('data-status', data.status ? 'locked' : 'unlocked')
            .addClass('asset-context box');
    }
} );
```

Comment: If you don't want the first TD but just want to add a class to your tr use this line: $(row).addClass('asset-context box');

Answer (score 14):

#### DataTable().row.add() situation:

If you want to add class when using row add function in Datatables, you could get the TR-DOM from `node()` method:

```
var datatable = $('#resultTable').DataTable();

var trDOM = datatable.row.add( [
    "Col-1",
    "Col-2"
] ).draw().node();

$( trDOM ).addClass('myClass');
```

Answer (score 12):

**To set the Id attribute on the row `<tr>` use:**

```
//.... 
rowId: "ShipmentId",
columns: [...],
//....
```

**To set a class name on the `<tr>` use this calback**

```
createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
    $(row).addClass('some-class-name');
},
```

ref: https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow

**To set a class on the `<td>` use**

```
"columns": [
{ 
    data:"",
    className: "my_class",
    render: function (data, type, row) { return "..."; }
},
{ 
    data:"",
    className: "my_class",
    render: function (data, type, row) { return "..."; }
},
//...
]
```

Something similar for 'columnDefs'

ref: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className

Comment: This adds it to the `<td>` not the `<tr>`

Comment: is any way to change the classname based on data into render function? 
so first define a default Classname and then in render function check if data is not valid change the classname

Comment: @vsam in this case you may wrap and cell contents inside a div or so and set the class name on it rather on the cell - the td - itself

Answer (score 5):

Also you can add class to `tr` by pass through json data that you send to datatable. It's enough that every json item has `DT_RowClass`.
**For example:**

```
{

    DT_RowAttr = new
    {
       attr1 = "1",
       attr2 = "2"
    }
    DT_RowClass = "majid",
    DT_RowId = "rowId"

}
```

In this example `DT_RowId` value apply to `id` attribute of any `tr` tag and `DT_RowAttr` value apply some custom attribute to `tr` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
createdRow: function (row,data) {
    var stsId = data.Ise_Sts_Cost_ID;
    if (stsId == 3)
        $(row).addClass('table-warning');
    else if (stsId == 4)
        $(row).addClass('table-success');
    else
        $(row).addClass('table-danger');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the stripeClasses option, which is used to set the row classname for the odd and even stripes.

```
stripeClasses: ['odd align-middle', 'even align-middle'],
```

In this example, I have attached the bootstrap 'align-middle' class to the original stripe classes, to vertically align the text within each row.

Ref: https://datatables.net/reference/option/stripeClasses