# How can I add class for <tr> in DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I trying to get value from each row with `<tr class="bill-row">` in datatable. so how do I set `class="bill-row"` in datatables ? so I can call ech row with

```
var row = $(".bill-row");

            row.each(function(i) {
                data.bill_number.push($("[name='bill_number[]']", this).val());
                data.service_charge.push($("[name='service_charge[]']", this).inputmask('unmaskedvalue'));
                // data.water_usage.push($("[name='water_usage[]']", this).inputmask('unmaskedvalue'));
                data.meteran_akhir_air.push($("[name='meteran_akhir_air[]']", this).inputmask('unmaskedvalue'));
                data.meteran_akhir.push($("[name='meteran_akhir[]']", this).inputmask('unmaskedvalue'));
```

set class to datatable like this

```
<tr class="bill-row" role="row">
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

default datatable

```
<tr role="row">
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

here's is my datatable to set class for `<tr>` but doesnt working

```
    createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
        $(row).addClass('bill-row');
    },
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640246/jquery-datatables-add-class-to-tr

Comment: Any errors inspecting? did you check the values of row?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) option is the correct way to do it.

For example:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  'createdRow': function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
      $(row).addClass( 'bill-row' );
  }
});
```

However you're retrieving rows incorrectly. Using `$(".bill-row")` will return rows on the current page only.

As an alternative use [`$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) API method instead.

For example:

```
var row = $('#example').DataTable().$('.bill-row');
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the `rowCallback` option:

```
table = $('#resultTable').DataTable({
    aaSorting: [],
    ajax: {...},
    columnDefs: [...],
    rowCallback: function (row, data) {
        if (data.IsDeleted) {
            $(row).addClass('redRow');
        }
    }
});
```

As seen on this [DataTables form page](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46697/adding-a-class-to-a-row-on-datatables-initialization).